# React Error: Cannot read property classList of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.showSideBar = this.showSideBar.bind(this);
}
showSideBar(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.sideBar.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

This is the error message: 
Header.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: It means that `this.sideBar` in your `showSideBar` function doesn't reference any object and is undefined. Have you tried: `this.classList.toggle("show")`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Unfortunately, I'm now getting this error message: Header.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined

Comment: Where is `sideBar` declared?

Comment: @ScottMarcus It's declared in another component that is being imported.

Comment: return(
   <aside className="sideBar" ref={ref => this.sideBar = ref}>

Comment: @ScottMarcus is that what you meant?

Comment: Your "this.sideBar" is referring to whatever class you declared above the constructor's sideBar. Maybe try removing the "this.". So, sideBar.classList.toggle("show")?

Comment: You cannot reference an object by its HTML `className` attribute. And, the attribute is actually just `class` not `className`. You use `className` in JavaScript to access the value of the `class` attribute.

Comment: @DataSwede didn't work... This is the error I'm getting:

Comment: Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/components/Header.js

/Users/apple/Sites/hackerYou/projects/secret-garden/src/components/Header.js
  3:8  warning  'Menu' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
  4:8  warning  'Cart' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
  5:8  warning  'plant' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
 16:3  error    'sideBar' is not defined           no-undef

:heavy_multiplication_x: 4 problems (1 error, 3 warnings)

Comment: You should post the code from your entire file. You have things imported that aren't used, and apparently never imported sideBar...

Comment: You literally do not have sideBar defined anywhere in your project. There is nothing in any of the files that says "sideBar = something_you_specify", so that's where your error is from. You need to create a sideBar class in another file and import it, or figure something else out.